# MVC Routing error shows up in my log, but unable to reproduce

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Url: http://www.nickkusters.com/SpeedTouch.aspx

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    // Legacy Reroutes
    Dictionary<String, String> ReRoutes = new Dictionary<string,string>();
    ReRoutes.Add("/speedtouch.aspx", "/Services/SpeedTouch");
    ReRoutes.Add("/Articles/79/online_speedtouch_wpa_key_lookup", "/Services/SpeedTouch");
    Dictionary<String, String> RegexReplace = new Dictionary<string,string>();
    RegexReplace.Add("^/css/(.*)", "/Content/$1");
    RegexReplace.Add("^/images/(.*)", "/Content/images/$1");
    RegexReplace.Add("^/articles/(\\d+)/(.*)\\.aspx", "/Articles/$1/$2");
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    CustomRouter.ReAssignHandler(RouteTable.Routes, ReRoutes, RegexReplace);
}
```

Custom Router:

```
public class CustomRouter : System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler
{
    internal static Dictionary<String, String> Custom301s;
    internal static Dictionary<String, String> Custom301Regexes;
    public CustomRouter(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext Context) : base(Context)
    {
    }
    public static void ReAssignHandler(System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection routes, Dictionary<String, String> CustomRoutes, Dictionary<String, String> CustomRouteRegexes)
    {
        using(routes.GetReadLock())
        {
            Custom301s = CustomRoutes;
            Custom301Regexes = CustomRouteRegexes;
            foreach (System.Web.Routing.Route Route in routes)
            {
                if(Route != null && Route.RouteHandler.GetType() != typeof(CustomRouteHandler))
                {
                    Route.RouteHandler = new CustomRouteHandler();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    protected override void ProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        String OriginalUrl, Url, UrlPath;
        OriginalUrl = httpContext.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
        Url = OriginalUrl;
        UrlPath = httpContext.Request.Url.AbsolutePath.ToLower();
        if(UrlPath.StartsWith("/WebResource.axd") ) 
        { 
            return;
        }
        if (Url.ToLower().StartsWith("http://buyinbulk.nl"))
        {
            Url = Url.ToLower().Replace("http://", "http://www.");
        }
        else if (Custom301s.ContainsKey(Url) )
        {
            Url = Custom301s[Url];
        }
        else if( Custom301s.ContainsKey(UrlPath) )
        {
            Url = Url.ToLower().Replace(UrlPath, Custom301s[UrlPath]);
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (String Pattern in Custom301Regexes.Keys)
            {
                if (Regex.Match(UrlPath, Pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Success )
                {
                    Url = Url.ToLower().Replace(UrlPath, Regex.Replace(UrlPath, Pattern, Custom301Regexes[Pattern], RegexOptions.IgnoreCase));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if(Url != OriginalUrl)
        {
            //mark as 301
            httpContext.Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
            httpContext.Response.StatusCode = 301;
            httpContext.Response.AppendHeader("Location", Url);
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                base.ProcessRequest(httpContext);
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Error Processing '{0}':\r\n{1}", OriginalUrl, Ex.ToString()));
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, my log keeps showing:

```
Url: http://www.nickkusters.com/SpeedTouch.aspx  
Message: System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): The controller for path '/SpeedTouch.aspx' was not found or does not implement IController.  
Stack Trace:    
at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)     
at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName)     
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory)     
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass6.<BeginProcessRequest>b__2()     
at System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<>c__DisplayClassb`1.<ProcessInApplicationTrust>b__a()     
at System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust[TResult](Func`1 func)     
at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()     
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

But if I open the url from different locations, it works just fine...